# How to make guided tour for web app in Flash or with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, apache-flex, user-interface

Do you know how to build something similar to

http://app.sliderocket.com/tour/GuidedTour.html?app=0&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=640&width=1030

I can see this is done in Flash, but I do not know how its done.

Also if there are anyt tools that can do something similar in JavaScript that would be nice to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search found http://touration.com/; I can't endorse them since I don't know them, but it might be worth a quick glance.

Comment: I'm curious: Why did you approve this answer over one and a half year later? ATM touration.com isn't even responding.

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds this ancient question I recommend [Shepherd](http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/).